# Firing javascript event based on time of day

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for help to see if there is an easy quick way to fire a JS event based on the time of day a website opens in the browser.

Essentially what I want to do is between 5pm-5am of the users local time zone have this script fire. The script is currently wired to a button that simply flips the class of the body of the page to "night mode". I would like the two to work in harmony, automate based on time and the ability to override with the button if you want the dark or light theme.

```
function toggleClass(element, className) {
if (!element || !className) {
    return;
}
var classString = element.className,
    nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
} else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex + className.length);
}
element.className = classString;
}

document.getElementById('day-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggleClass(document.getElementById('body'), 'night');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/simpson/57xe333n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time = new Date();
element = document.getElementById('body');
className = "night";
console.log(time.getHours());
if(time.getHours() > 17 || time.getHours < 5) {
    if (!element || !className) {
        return;
    }
    var classString = element.className,
        nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
    if (nameIndex == -1) {
        classString += ' ' + className;
    } else {
        classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex + className.length);
    }
    element.className = classString;
}
```

This uses JS's built in Date functionalities which pull from the system. It runs a getHours() function which returns an int(0-23). The if statement `(time.getHours() > 17 || time.getHours < 5)` will then only run the code and change the theme if it is after 5pm or before 5 am. Hope this can get you started.